# MediathekView does not start in Kubuntu 18.10 (cosmic)

Tags: kubuntu, java, 18.10, jar

In Kubuntu 18.10 (cosmic) the application [MediathekView](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/mediathekview) crashes with the following error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jidesoft/utils/ThreadCheckingRepaintManager
```

Remark: the message is only visible when MediathekView is started from a console using the command `mediathekview`. When MediathekView is started from the launcher nothing happens (no error message, no nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove MediathekView and use [MediathekViewWeb](https://mediathekviewweb.de/) instead. It has less features (see the [readme](https://github.com/mediathekview/mediathekviewweb/blob/master/README.md), German only) but it does not require any installation.

Answer (score 1):

This issue does not exist with full versions of MediathekView which can be downloaded from the official website [here](https://download.mediathekview.de/stabil/MediathekView-latest.tar.gz); this version comes with the missing libraries inside a `lib` folder; version 13.2.1, the latest at the time of this answer worked well for me. The installation only consists of unpacking the archive. The file `MediathekView.jar` starts the application, the `lib` folder is required for the application to start.

Starting MediathekView using the command `java -jar MediathekView.jar` will not work though; this new error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/concurrent/Task
```

[For some reason JavaFX is not found.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=910395) First you must make sure that the package [`libopenjfx-java`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/libopenjfx-java) is installed; since it is a dependency of MediathekView it should be already installed. Then all the JAR files for JavaFX must be added by hand to the class path when starting MediathekView:

```
java -cp MediathekView.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-base-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-controls-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-fxml-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-graphics-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-media-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-swing-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-web-11.jar mediathek.Main
```

You can add a path in front of `MediathekView.jar` to match the location where you unpacked the installation package.

MediathekView should start, the splash screen will not work though.

And MediathekView has a picky Java version check built in and will complain about with some specific JDK release numbers; for instance OpenJDK 11 will work but not the bug fixed version OpenJDK 11.0.1.

Comment: As suggested by the alternative answer by obri you can edit the start script /usr/bin/mediathekview to put the command which will start your "fixed" version of MediathekView instead of the one shipped with Ubuntu. This will be reverted when MediathekView gets updated by the package manager.

Comment: A security fix for the OpenJDK Java runtime bearing the version 11.0.1 was just released and MediathekView complains again, this time about the version of Java. You can go back to the version 11 at your own risk by installing [openjdk-11-jre](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre_11~28-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb) and [openjdk-11-jre-headless](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11~28-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb) in the older version 11 (before the security fix).

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the following line:

```
java -cp MediathekView.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-base-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-controls-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-fxml-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-graphics-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-media-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-swing-11.jar:/usr/share/java/javafx-web-11.jar mediathek.Main
```

in the file `mediathekview.sh`.
Put it in the first line after the comments, then it will work if you run `mediathekview.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried this too and it didn't work for me. I still get the error message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jidesoft/utils/ThreadCheckingRepaintManager.

Comment: I just tried this with a live USB of Kubuntu 18.10 (cosmic) and the above command alone does not solve the problem. The JIDE Common Layer (com/jidesoft/*) is still missing and the same error is thrown. Did you copy the missing libraries and forgot to describe this step in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't "just copy that line". If you do, you'll receive the very next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:   
javafx/concurrent/Task has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime  
(class file version 54.0),  
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 –
```

because the `lib`s lead to classes compiled by JDK11, and not JDK8.

Comment: You need OpenJDK 11 (not OpenJDK 11.0.1!). This version can run OpenJFX and will pass the version check in MediathekView. OpenJFX used to come in a version compatible to OpenJDK 8 with older releases of Ubuntu but downgrading to the old version of the OpenJFX packages did not work for me (I don't remember the details).

Comment: A small hint on the side: this seems to be a comment on the answer proposed by obri. As such it should be posted under the comment section of his answer and not as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check version of openjfx ("sudo apt install openjfx" installs it or returns the version). I am on 18.04 LTS. So it was 1.8.xx.
Concerning java I have several versions installed. When not the corresponding version is chosen (8) this error was reported.
To switch versions use "sudo update-alternatives --config java" which indicates which versions are installed, which is chosen and which number you have to insert to switch. To recheck you can enter "java --version".

Comment: Hello Andreas, thank you for your suggestion. I think there is no issue with bionic (I updated from bionic to cosmic). OpenJFX only comes in one version in each version of Ubuntu; [version 8 for bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libopenjfx-java) and [version 11 for cosmic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/libopenjfx-java). In cosmic OpenJDK 11.0.1 breaks the version check of MV and OpenJDK 8 lacks OpenJFX. Installing the older OpenJFX 8 from bionic in cosmic breaks dependencies. Basically there is no easy solution.